# How can I draw a function generator in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

The element that I want to add in my circuit is this function generator:

[image]

Here is the code for what I've donde so far:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.up) --++(0,0.5) node[vcc]{12\,\textnormal{V}}
(opamp.down) --++(0,-0.5) node[vee]{-12\,\textnormal{V}}
(opamp.-) to [R, l_= 1 k$\Omega$] ($(opamp.-)+(-3,0)$)
(opamp.-) to [short] ($(opamp.-)+(0,3)$)
($(opamp.-)+(0,3)$) to [R, l = $R_F$] ($(opamp.-)+(3,3)$)
($(opamp.-)+(3,3)$) to [short] ($(opamp.out)+(0.64,0)$)
(opamp.out) to [short,-o] ($(opamp.out)+(2,0)$)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

This is the full circuit (just for reference).

[image]

Comment: Hi Mario, this is not a schematic symbol - the best bet is to create it in Ti*k*Z, for example as a `pic`. I know that there are similar things in the library, like the oscilloscope, but  I do not think that this symbol is general enough... I will try a shot at it if I have a bit of time.

Comment: I would just go ahead and use the image.  You can use coordinates relative to the node position for the connections.

Answer (score 1):

I know probably it's not the answer you are looking for, but given that this is a schematic, I'll go with this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \coordinate (start) at (0,0);
    \draw (start) -- ++(0,-0.5)
        node[rotary switch <-=3 in 90 wiper -90, anchor=in, rotate=-90](SW){};
    \draw (SW.aout 3) -- ++(-1,0) to[sqV, name=sq-gen]
        ++(0,-3) coordinate(gGND);
    \draw (SW.aout 2) to[sV, -*] (SW.aout 2 |- gGND)
        -- ++(0,-0.5) node[tlground]{};
    \draw (SW.aout 1) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(tmp) to[tV, name=t-gen]
        (tmp |- gGND) -- (gGND);
    \node[draw, dashed, fit=(SW) (gGND) (sq-gen) (t-gen), inner sep=0.3cm]
    (signal generator){};
    \node[right] at (signal generator.east) {\texttt{XFR1}};
    \node [ocirc] at (signal generator.north){};
    \node [ocirc] at (signal generator.south){};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...you can move it anywhere by changing the `(start)` coordinate. It's not so fancy as your idea, but it's electrically correct.